# JAVA Wildcard Capture Error with an array of generic stacks

Tags: java, arrays, generics, stack, bounded-wildcard

```
Stack<?>[] stacks = {
    new Stack<Bed>(),
    new Stack<Bookshelves>(),
    new Stack<Chair>(),
    new Stack<Desk>(),
    new Stack<Table>()
};
```

That's the code making the array of stacks. The reason I'm putting them in an array is because it's one of the requirements for the Assignment. The program works without the array.

Also, the Stack takes in generics because I had to create my own Stack (also a requirement of the Assignment).

```
while(sc.hasNext()){
    temp = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
    if(temp[0].equals("Bed")){
        //beds.push(new Bed(temp[1], temp[2]));
        stacks[0].push(new Bed(temp[1], temp[2]));
    }else if(temp[0].equals("Table")){
        //tables.push(new Table(Integer.parseInt(temp[1]), Integer.parseInt(temp[2]), Integer.parseInt(temp[3]), temp[4]));
        stacks[4].push(new Table(Integer.parseInt(temp[1]), Integer.parseInt(temp[2]), Integer.parseInt(temp[3]), temp[4]));
    }else if(temp[0].equals("Desk")){
        //desks.push(new Desk(temp[1],temp[2], Integer.parseInt(temp[3]), Integer.parseInt(temp[4])));
        stacks[3].push(new Desk(temp[1],temp[2], Integer.parseInt(temp[3]), Integer.parseInt(temp[4])));
    }else if(temp[0].equals("Chair")){
        //chairs.push(new Chair(temp[1], temp[2]));
        stacks[2].push(new Chair(temp[1], temp[2]));
    }else if(temp[0].equals("Bookshelves")){
        //bookshelves.push(new Bookshelves(Integer.parseInt(temp[1]), Integer.parseInt(temp[2]), Integer.parseInt(temp[3]), Integer.parseInt(temp[4]), temp[5]));
        stacks[1].push(new Bookshelves(Integer.parseInt(temp[1]), Integer.parseInt(temp[2]), Integer.parseInt(temp[3]), Integer.parseInt(temp[4]), temp[5]));
    }else{
        color = temp[0];
    }
}
```

This code gets the information from the text file and pushes the Objects into the stack.

I get an Error saying:

```
push(capture#627 of ?) in Stack<capture#627 of ?> cannot be applied to (Bed)
```

This Error repeats for all the Classes that I have created.

The parts commented out is the code that worked before when I made a single stack for each Object.

I can't put everything into the array after I have pushed everything into the Stack because points will be taken out for unnecessary intermediate variables.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this properly and type-safely is either

a) combine this all into one `Stack<Furniture>` (assuming the classes all extend `Furniture`)

b) keep separate variables for each stack, and get rid of the array entirely.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Also, doing the 'b' option isn't allowed for the assignment.

Comment: I did mean it when I said that these were the _only_ ways to do this properly or type-safely.  The alternative is to lose type-safety and start doing unsafe raw casts: `(Stack) stacks[0].push` will take any `Object`.  Ewwwwwwwwww.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why an assignment would require this. Seems like it's teaching poor design.

Comment: Indeed.  If I was asked to review code like this, I'd refuse to continue the review until this was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
((Stack<Bed>)stacks[0]).push(new Bed(temp[1], temp[2]));
```